# How to use OS or Arch specific code in Go

Tags: go

Apparently, `syscall.Dup2` does not exist on ARM systems, and `syscall.Dup3` does not exisxt on darwin (OSX). This means I could use `syscall.Dup3` on ARM, and `syscall.Dup2` on other platforms, for example.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a wrapper source file per unique code configuration.

*PS:* I think windows supports neither `Dup2` nor `Dup3`.

*syscall_wrapper.go*

```
// +build !windows
// +build !arm
// +build !arm64

package mypkg

import (
    "syscall"
)

func Dup2(oldfd int, newfd int) {
    syscall.Dup2(oldfd, newfd)
}
```

*syscall_wrapper_arm.go*

```
// +build !windows
// +build arm arm64

package mypkg

import (
    "syscall"
)

func Dup2(oldfd int, newfd int) {
    syscall.Dup3(oldfd, newfd, 0)
}
```

The essential part, used for example by `go build`, is the `// +build` part. Details for how to use this can be found here:

- [Build Constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints)
- [OS & Arch values](https://gist.github.com/asukakenji/f15ba7e588ac42795f421b48b8aede63#go-golang-goos-and-goarch)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `golang.org/x/sys/unix` library for this

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

unix.Dup2(oldfd, newfd)
```